# Run method in background worker

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, backgroundworker

I want to run to of my methods in background worker in my windows form.
On completion of each methods the output generated by those method will be presented in the label.

I have very less knowledge in background worker. Can some one guide me how this can be accomplish. I tired but it says the thread cannot access the controls in the form.

Here is the code for my two methods and both will be executed in same time when button is clicked by the user.

```
 private void program_green()
        {
            string stdOut = null;
            string stdError = null;
            string address = "192.168.1.100";
            string user = "user";
            string pass = "password";
            SshExec ssh = new SshExec(address, user, pass);
            ssh.Connect();
            ssh.RunCommand("cfg_green " + green_textBox1.Text + " " + green_textBox2.Text + " " + green_textBox3.Text, ref stdOut, ref stdError);
            green_output.Text = stdOut;
            ssh.Close();

        }

        private void program_grey()
        {
            string stdOut = null;
            string stdError = null;
            string address = "192.168.1.100";
            string user = "user";
            string pass = "password";
            SshExec ssh = new SshExec(address, user, pass);
            ssh.Connect();
            ssh.RunCommand("cfg_grey " + grey_textBox1.Text + " " + grey_textBox2.Text + " " + grey_textBox3.Text, ref stdOut, ref stdError);
            grey_output.Text = stdOut;
            ssh.Close();
        }
```

Any support will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following links -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/841751/MultiThreading-Using-a-Background-Worker-Csharp

In the `DoWork` event of the worker, just call both of your methods. In case you want to track and handle both the methods individually, have 2 background workers in place.

And at the click of you button, call the `RunWorkerAsync` method of the worker object

Answer (score 0):

```
class BackgroundWork
{
    private Thread thread1;

    private Thread thread2;

    private void StartObserving() {

       thread1 = new Thread(this.program_green);

       thread1.Start();

       thread2 = new Thread(this.program_grey);

       thread2.Start();
    }


 }
```

Comment: Add some description also along with code

Comment: program_green and program_grey are two methods give in above code

Comment: The question is about background worker, a winform component. Threading, (tough sounds similar if one is not aware of the component) is quiet a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

This link have a good somple
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

It's important to access UI components by UI(Main) thread.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // background process by worker thread
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // handled the event by UI thread.
}
```